# Load div-Tab only OnClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, tabs, onclick

I don't know how to add in that code a on click action. The problem is that i have to create a page with more than 600 pictures, which is very heavy to load on page load. So i've for each group of pictures a tab which i want to load only by click. In the code is now only one tab to show my problem.
The function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#mycarousel-1, #mycarousel-2, #mycarousel-3, #mycarousel-4, #mycarousel-5, #mycarousel-6, #mycarousel-7').jcarousel({
            horisontal: true,
            wrap:'circular',
            scroll:1,
            easing:'easeInOutBack',
            animation:1200
        });
```

The Menu:

```
<section id="content">
    <div class="page3-row1 pad-2 tabs">
        <div class="col-8">
            <h2 class="h2 p2">Categorie:</h2>
            <div class="demo-container clear">
            <ul class="list-1 nav">
                <li><a href="#tab-1-modern">Modern Design</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
   </div>
```

The code:

```
<div class="col-9">
     <h3 class="h3-2">Design's:</h3> 
    <div id="tab-1-modern" class="tab-content gallery-photo">
        <div class="inner">
            <ul id="mycarousel-1" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
                <li><a class="plus"     href="images/modern-001-big_b.jpg"><img src="images/modern-001_b.jpg" alt=""></a><a class="plus"     href="images/modern-002-big_b.jpg"><img src="images/modern-002_b.jpg" alt=""></a><a class="plus"     href="images/modern-003-big_b.jpg"><img src="images/modern-003_b.jpg" alt=""></a><a class="plus"     href="images/modern-004-big_b.jpg"><img src="images/modern-004_b.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
                        <li><a class="plus"     href="images/modern-005-big_b.jpg"><img src="images/modern-005_b.jpg" alt=""></a><a class="plus"     href="images/modern-006-big_b.jpg"><img src="images/modern-006_b.jpg" alt=""></a><a class="plus"     href="images/modern-007-big_b.jpg"><img src="images/modern-007_b.jpg" alt=""></a><a class="plus"     href="images/modern-008-big_b.jpg"><img src="images/modern-008_b.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
                        <li><a class="plus"     href="images/modern-009-big_b.jpg"><img src="images/modern-009_b.jpg" alt=""></a><a class="plus"     href="images/modern-010-big_b.jpg"><img src="images/modern-010_b.jpg" alt=""></a><a class="plus"     href="images/modern-011-big_b.jpg"><img src="images/modern-011_b.jpg" alt=""></a><a class="plus"     href="images/modern-012-big_b.jpg"><img src="images/modern-012_b.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
                        <li><a class="plus"     href="images/modern-013-big_b.jpg"><img src="images/modern-013_b.jpg" alt=""></a><a class="plus"     href="images/modern-014-big_b.jpg"><img src="images/modern-014_b.jpg" alt=""></a><a class="plus"     href="images/modern-015-big_b.jpg"><img src="images/modern-015_b.jpg" alt=""></a><a class="plus"     href="images/modern-016-big_b.jpg"><img src="images/modern-016_b.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

in the code above are now also the pictures.

Comment: Where does the HTML for image go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid from what you've given so far this is the best I can do...

```
$('#mycarousel-1 li').click(function() {
  // code here to load the images...
});
```

[Edit]

```
    <div class="col-9">
     <h3 class="h3-2">Design's:</h3> 
    <div id="tab-1-modern" class="tab-content gallery-photo">
        <div class="inner">
            <ul id="mycarousel-1" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
                <li><a class="plus" thishref="images/modern-001-big_b.jpg"><img src="images/modern-001_b.jpg" alt=""></a><a class="plus"     href="images/modern-002-    big_b.jpg"><img src="images/modern-002_b.jpg" alt=""></a><a class="plus"     href="images/modern-003-big_b.jpg"><img src="images/modern-003_b.jpg" alt=""></a><a class="plus"     href="images/modern-004-big_b.jpg"><img src="images/modern-004_b.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
                <li><a class="plus" thishref="images/modern-005-big_b.jpg"><img src="images/modern-005_b.jpg" alt=""></a><a class="plus"     href="images/modern-006-big_b.jpg"><img src="images/modern-006_b.jpg" alt=""></a><a class="plus"     href="images/modern-007-big_b.jpg"><img src="images/modern-007_b.jpg" alt=""></a><a class="plus"     href="images/modern-008-big_b.jpg"><img src="images/modern-008_b.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
                <li><a class="plus" thishref="images/modern-009-big_b.jpg"><img src="images/modern-009_b.jpg" alt=""></a><a class="plus"     href="images/modern-010-big_b.jpg"><img src="images/modern-010_b.jpg" alt=""></a><a class="plus"     href="images/modern-011-big_b.jpg"><img src="images/modern-011_b.jpg" alt=""></a><a class="plus"     href="images/modern-012-big_b.jpg"><img src="images/modern-012_b.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
                <li><a class="plus" thishref="images/modern-013-big_b.jpg"><img src="images/modern-013_b.jpg" alt=""></a><a class="plus"     href="images/modern-014-big_b.jpg"><img src="images/modern-014_b.jpg" alt=""></a><a class="plus"     href="images/modern-015-big_b.jpg"><img src="images/modern-015_b.jpg" alt=""></a><a class="plus"     href="images/modern-016-big_b.jpg"><img src="images/modern-016_b.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and script as follows:

```
$('#mycarousel-1 a').click(function() {
  // this loads each image the same, but you can use the same technique to
  // load the correct images for each image
  var imgurl = $(this).attr('thishref');
  $(this).find('img').each(function() {
      $(this).attr('src',imgurl);
  });
});
```

[/Edit]

Comment: i can't solve the problem.i've tried it many times, so if you need more code to help me, i'll uploud it.

Comment: Sure. Can you explain a bit more about what it should do? e.g.: "when a tab is clicked, load `'myimage.png'` into a div in the tab"

Comment: Ok...What i want is, when you click in the menu on "<li><a href="#tab-1-modern">Modern Design</a></li>" it should load the tab below. Now it loads all tabs by loading the page.

Comment: Ok check out the part in the `[Edit]` tags - is this nearer to what you need?